# SCSS add animation based on id

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sass

I am including runtime class for animation. Two DIV with different id's  [`front` , `back`] have same classes [`flip`] added on Click.
can i add different animation based on Id

JSX:

```
<div className="card">
       <div id="front" className={frontClasses.join(' ')} 
 onClick={clickedFront}>
          OPEN
        </div>
  <div id="back" className={backClasses.join(' ')} >
          {props.inputNum}
  </div>
```

**In SCSS**

This works

```
   .flip {
          transform:rotateY(180deg);        
     }
```

and is not working

```
   .flip {
      #front {
          transform:rotateY(180deg);
        }
       #back {
          transform:rotateY(0deg);
        }
   }
```

I want to rotate the div only with id `front`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `&` for SCSS nesting `&#front`

You can just use `#front.flip` though.

```css
.flip {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#front.flip {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip"></div>
<div class="flip" id="front"></div>
```